1990s movie: lithium, bipolar rich heiress, murder plot
This was definitely a Hollywood movie released around mid 1990s, but action could take bit earlier - maybe around 1960s
Protagonist (a mid-20s actor, for some reason I keep thinking about younger John Cusack, but after checking IMDB I don't think its him) meets a happy, carefree, hippie girl in a pub and they spend night together - although later her happiness fades and it seems that she is really terrified of something or someone. She runs away, but the main character decides to find her.
He does, but she behaves completely different now - instead of very open, passionate woman there is now an Ice Queen - cold, calculated, dressed in rich clothes - the only thing that disturbs this statue-like perfection are her shaking hands: She explains (coldly of course) that she suffers from mental illness and without lithium, that causes her hands to shake, she turns into "overly emotional" other self and that she usually have no recollections of other one's action (she is quite resentful about their night together, she says something like "you got lucky and scored, now get out!")
Now here my memory gets bit vague: I know that this woman is rich heiress and there is a plot that tries to either lock her in the mental institution or force her to kill herself (or someone else), but she doesn't believe that any of people close to her would be able to do so, until, towards end of the movie, the protagonist mentions that "your hands stopped shaking... I guess they've improved the lithium pills". 
